# Side by side display of two sections

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner, and, as it is in case of most beginners, I'm struggling with something I feel should be simpler than it is for me at the moment.

As a part of my task, I am to create a layout for a blog entry, whereby the date and the author would be represented in the column to the left (`roundel-container` in the code below), whereas the content itself (`articlebody`) and the footer with "read more" button and links to comments (`readmore-footer`) would form the second, wider column to the right. [This image represents a simplified vision of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRZwd.png).

I've been playing around with `position:`, `left:`, `right:` and `float:`, but to mediocre results (which I might well owe to lack of practice). Here's how the code looks like now:

HTML

```
<section class="articlebox">
    <section class="roundel-container">
        <div class="roundel left"><span class="bold">11 Nov 2013</span></div>
        <div class="roundel left"><span class="bold">by John Doe</span></div>
    </section>
    <section class="articlebody">
        <p class="readable">Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    </section>
    <footer id="readmore-footer">
        <div class="button bold white" id="readmore-button">Read More</div>
        <section class="right">
            <p><a class="darkblue">10 likes</a> <a class="darkblue">22 comments</a></p>
        </section>
    </footer>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.articlebody {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0px 15px 10px 15px;
}

.articlebox {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.roundel {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #22aaec;
    display: flex;              
    flex-direction: column;     
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;    
    align-items: center;
}

.roundel-container {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 220px;
}

#readmore-footer {
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
}

.button {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
}
```

I'd appreciate help with this one, as well as any tips and tricks you might give regarding the above. Thanks!

Comment: why didn't you use bootstrap for this?

Comment: The task is about not using .js and in the same time ensuring compatibility with IE8. I'm not sure it's possible to make Bootstrap work as it should in IE8 without JavaScript.

Comment: ok, i post very simple method for this in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently started flex-boxing all of the things to achieve layouts such as the one you ask for. Read this article, it should help you get the structure you are looking for. I try to stay away from using floats when possible.

http://markheath.net/post/simple-css-blog-layout-flexbox

Comment: Thanks, will be useful in many more instances, from what I see! :)

Answer (score 2):

write your code like this:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    div.container {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
    
    header, footer {
        padding: 1em;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        clear: left;   
    }
    
    nav {
        float: left;
        max-width: 160px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1em;
    }
    
    nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
       
    nav ul a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    article {
        margin-left: 170px;
        border-left: 1px solid gray;
        
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">  
    <nav>
      <p>roundel container</p>
    </nav>
    <article>
      <p>article body</p>
      <footer>readmore footer</footer>
    </article>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

note: this is just demo that will give you idea. Hope it will helps you. Cheers!

Comment: Great, and for further i will suggest you to read from w3schools.com.